# 2 Formulas in Excel 2007

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am completely new to excel (started this week).

I am trying to use 2 formulas in one cell.

Eg. I have a formula such as

```
=(L3+M3)/100*3.4
```

I end up with a number such as 2.0298 and I would like to show it to 2 decimal places.

I'm assuming I would need to use the round formula but **how do I do this**? Can I use **autofill** to apply it to multiple cells?

Sorry if this is a very basic question but I'm quite impressed at what I've achieved with only a few hours tuition.

Answer (score 1):

There are two things you can do, both of which have different effects

1) You can round the number:

```
=ROUND((L3+M3)/100*3.4,2)
```

In which case the rounded number (2.03 in your example) will be used in subsequent calculations

2) You can change the display of the number by clicking the rightmost icon of the `Number` section of the `HOME` tab

[image]

In which case the number will display as rounded, but the unrounded number (2.0298 in your example) will be used in subsequent calculations

Comment: Correct. How embarrassing...